# How to close windows 8 store app from background task

Tags: windows, winrt-xaml

I have a windows 8 store app and a Background task is also associated with it. Everything working fine. And my question is, is there any possibility to close my app from BackgroundTask Run method ?

thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

**No**, You can't do that instantly!

But you could save a file in your app's local storage -or settings- and let the foreground app check for this file every 10 minutes -whatever- and close the app in a specific condition ..

Comment: Thanks for answering my question, closing app unexpectedly also a bad idea, yes i took a wrong decision of creating a background task for my goal and even without background task also i can achieve my goal. and i have finished my goal without background task now. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Your background task can be hosted in its own dedicated process or it can be hosted in the same process as your UI. In a separate process your foreground app can open and close without impacting your background process. In the shared process when your foreground app closes, so does the background task. This is not true in reverse, the shared process model does not allow a closing background task to close the foreground app. Too bad, huh?

Technically, it is not recommend that a foreground application close itself. But, hey, that API is there for something, right? When the background task shares the process with the foreground app then it can communicate directly between them with shared memory. This would introduce method 1 for communicating from your background task to your foreground app - **probably by using a static event**.

If that's not what you want, and you need separate processes, then your options are a bit more tricky.

**Here's the best option:**

You set a special setting (let's say it's `ApplicationData.LocalSettings.Values["DataFromBackground"] = "PleaseExit"`) and then call the `ApplicationData.`[SignalDataChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.signaldatachanged.aspx) method from the background task which will raise the `ApplicationData.`[DataChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.datachanged.aspx) event handled by the foreground app. How much lag will there be? I am not sure, but there will be some, so be ready for that.

> Be sure an remember to set `DataFromBackground` back to some empty value, including calling `Value.Remove()` so you don't mistakenly process it again. That being said, you should also poll for that value when your application launches (or resumes) in case your background task wrote it while the event could not be heard.

This is probably the easiest way to implement communication.

Make sense? **I speak more on this in my [Ignite session](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Ignite/2015/BRK3344) on the topic.**

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for answering my question, closing app unexpectedly also a bad idea, yes i took a wrong decision of creating a background task for my goal and even without background task also i can achieve my goal. and i have finished my goal without background task now. thanks again.